# How to fetch data from GA4 to ADF?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to get data from Google Analysis 4 to Azure Data Factory. So I can process the data from Google Analysis 4 into Azure Data Factory.

I haven't tried it at the moment, this the first time I'm using it but I'll like to know about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.